# Tessellation of a grid with squares and triangles

Tags: geometry

A set S of unit squares is chosen out of a large grid of unit squares. The squares of S are tiled with isosceles right triangles of hypotenuse 2 so that the triangles do not overlap each other, do not extend past S, and all of S is fully covered by the triangles. Additionally, the hypotenuse of each triangle lies along a grid line, and the vertices of the triangles lie at the corners of the squares. Show that the number of triangles must be a multiple of 4.

Comment: This question comes from the current USAMTS Round 3 problem set ([problem 5](http://www.usamts.org/Tests/Problems_26_3.pdf)). This question will remain locked until after the submission deadline of 19 Jan 2015.

Comment: This was a problem asked during an open mathematical competition for the purposes of gaining an unnatural and unfair advantage. It had been locked and hidden. Although it is now unlocked, since the competition has passed, this is abusive and bad; and I downvoted. It is unfortunate, as the question is pleasant and the answer good.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, the only way to place the triangle in a grid would be like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Axk.jpg

Then, to complete a 2x2 square in the grid, you need 4 triangles. It is not possible to create a 3x3 or 5x5 or any other odd no square using the triangles.